# Apache2 - going to https even when ssl is disabled

Tags: apache, http, https

I have spent 1 full day on this and I am tired. Any help will be appreciated

Problem:
Rails app. Working perfectly on development machine. Deployed it on production machine - Ubuntu 10.04, Apache2 /2.2.14, mysql, Using Passenger for Rails.

Whenever I tried to access with serverName in the browser, the url will become https:// serverName and the page will not be displayed.

I ended up enabling ssl and generating a certificate. The site works with a warning - "not trusted. do you want to proceed". I am fine with that.

But I am trying to run it on http and nto redirect to https.

- I disabled ssl mode with sudo a2dismod ssl
- removed default-ssl from sites-enabled

Now ssl is disabled but still when I go to browser and type the server address or ip, it appends https to it and says 'This webpage is not available'

It is not the browser issue because I am able to access the other server (not owned by me) with http.
Also the app runs fine with http on my localhost in the same browser.

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me with disabling https completly on apache2.

Comment: You haven't got a redirect somewhere in the script / your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I have not set any. Updated the description that I am using passenger as this is a rails app, if that can lead to the problem. The only .htaccess files I can find is in the paths similar to - /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.23/test/stub/rails_apps/2.3/mycook/public/.htaccess and I cannot see any redirect there.

Comment: Use curl or another tool to find out how the browser is getting redirected.  Double-check that you don't have any extensions in your local browser which may be doing the redirection.

Comment: Thanks guys. I got it. Posted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found out why the redirect was happening.
Everything was working fine on local but not in the production environment, even after disabling SSL on apache. It was rails which was redirecting it on https.
Had to do this

```
config.force_ssl = false
```

in config/environments/production.rb